# OpenGL: optimizing render of quad particles

Tags: iphone, opengl-es, particles

I'm rendering particles in a 2D game. Each particle is a quad (2 triangles). How can I make the drawing the fastest possible? All the particles has the same texture, I'm only changing it's positions.

Now I'm using a call to glVertexPointer and glDrawArrays for each particle. So I'm sending 4 vertices each time to the GPU.

Is there any other approach that could be faster?

I'm using OpenGL ES 1.1 (iPhone)

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Every draw call you make (glDrawArrays) is expensive. Doing this once per particle is DEFINITELY way too often. All your particles can be drawn with a single draw call; just set up a big array of all the triangle verts and another big array with the texture coords, and call glVertexPointer/glDrawArrays once-- that's the power of glVertexPointer: arbitrary geometry of the same type in one call. :)

For what you're doing, you should also look into point sprites (GL_POINTS), which also function as tiny textured quads. They're 2D only, so you can't map your texture into the Z axis, but if your particles are just 2D quads of the same texture over and over, point sprites will likely do exactly what you want.

Comment: So, to call glDrawArrays just one time, I should add extra degenerate vertices? or should I use GL_TRIANGLES? I think any of both ways I'd be using 2 more vertices per particle, right? That's 50% more vertices than what I'm using right now, will it be faster anyway?

Comment: So you're using strips or fans now (you didn't mention). Yeah, you'd use triangles instead. Try it out and compare. :) If your number of particles is meaningfully high (hundreds? thousands?) the current number of draw calls is killing your frame rate. This test should be easy to do. Point sprites would require more modification, but would result in much fewer verts (one point per particle, and no texture coords).

Comment: Yes, I'm using strips now. A coworker is also telling me to use glDrawElements to send fewer vertices (4 per quad), but I should send the indexes too... do you think that may help?

Comment: @Damian: I don't have a lot of experience with DrawElements. Any of these techniques is likely to help you, but only trying it out will tell you for sure. I CAN tell you that every draw call is expensive, and if you're making something you expect to run at 60fps, your number of draw calls per frame should be be small. Like single digits if you can do it.

Comment: Setting up an array and copying all particles vertices to that array on each frame, and then making a single call to glVertexPointer/glDrawArrays (using GL_TRIANGLE) I got over 2x the fps I was having! Thanks a lot for the help.

Comment: You could use glDrawElements and [VBOs](http://www.opengl.org/wiki/Vertex_Specification#Vertex_Buffer_Object), then update only the vertices coordinates since indices are already loaded in GPU memory.

Answer (score 0):

There's a way to do that all in one draw routine. I THINK it's by adding an extra vertex after each quad, which is the same as the previous vertex, but I could be wrong.

EDIT: After looking into it a bit, it looks like you need two in between; essentially one after, and one before. It does add up to quite a few extra vertexes, but I know from experience that it makes a HUGE positive difference on the iPhone to do it all in one draw operation (we were drawing text from a texture, so essentially the same thing).

EDIT2: Also note, I'm referring to using GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP - if you were using GL_TRIANGLES instead, you wouldn't need the extra vertices... except, then you'd be doing the same amount extra anyway, due to repeating 2 for each second triangle.